# No published artifact found in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting a warning on my `PublishArtifact` step.

> ##[warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'app'.

I'm new to Pipelines and can not figure out why it's empty, here is my configuration

```
variables:
  System.Debug: true

trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/question-ui'
    Contents: '**/*'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: 'package.json'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    # rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/question-ui'
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    artifactName: app

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'app'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'removed'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'qt-question-ui-ws'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'QT-WS-DEV'
    SlotName: 'production'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.AritifactsDirectory)/app/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

The archive file is saving to `/home/vsts/work/1/s/87.zip` but I'm not sure how to point my PublishArtifact to that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need on the `archiveFile: '$(Build.BuildId).zip'` to add the Artifacts folder in the path:

```
archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```